# Python split dictionary key at comma

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary called muncounty- the keys are municipality, county. separted by a comma and the value is a zip code

```
 muncounty['mun'+','+'county'] = 12345
```

My goal is to split the keys at the comma separating the mun and county and only extract the mun.

I have tried

```
muncounty.keys().split(',')
```

- i know this does not work because you cannot use the split function on a list

Comment: my bad forget the quotes-still does not work

Comment: Looks like you have to split the elements of the lists. Use an iteration.

Comment: There's too much wrong here for one question. You're calling split incorrectly and on the wrong object, you're trying to do something to every member of a list without looping. And fundamentally you're just forming the dict badly. Instead of using this complicated compound string key, why not just have a nested dict like `muncounty[municipality_name][county_name] = zip_code` or whatever?

Comment: so loop into the key name?

Comment: gotcha okay il give that a try. sorry guys i am pretty new to python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of looping, e.g. a list comprehension:

```
[key.split(',') for key in muncounty.keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question and example code isn't very clear, but I think what you want is this:

```
for key in muncounty.keys():
    mun, county = key.split(',')
```

Your current code is trying to perform `split` on a `list`, which you quite rightly point out can't be done. What the code above does is go through each key, and performs the `split` on it individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use map and a lambda function.

```
di = {'a.b':1}
map(lambda k: k.split('.'), di.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

`[x.split(',')[0] for x in muncounty.keys()]`

But I would recommend to store your key as tuple (municipality, county).

Answer (score 0):

Well, verbose mode for that:

```
muncounty = {}
muncounty['mun'+','+'county'] = 12345
muncounty['mun2'+','+'county2'] = 54321

l = []
for i in muncounty:
    l.append(i)

muns = []

for k in l:
    muns.append(k.split(',')[0])
```

But dude... this is a really bad way to store mun/countries ;-)

Comment: I realized its a bad way after reading peoples responses to my question lol-why though? ps im a few months new to python

Comment: Because you need to loop all dict and split strings on each iteration. This is not escalable.  What do you really want to do ? :-)

Comment: I am updating 1.csv address layer with municipalities and no zip codes. from a 2. csv with just county, municipalities, and zips. So I am looping through the 2. csv extracting that info then looping thru the 1. address csv and matching the municipalities and adding the zips to it

Comment: It's ok. But after this step you should store it in some other format to use it. Simpler way can be something like my_dict['BR','Fortaleza'] = 63040-360.

Comment: But my preference is to create objects to store countries and inside it include a set of objects like cities / neighborhood / zip codes.